# Help with BIND9 DNS Can you clarify why I still can't see my domain outside my local network

Tags: dns

**This is my configuration in BIND9**

> /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 192.168.1.24
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
search fabyfashion.com
```

> /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
            acl "trusted" {
            192.168.1.64; #LAPTOP-3BEQ0U93
    };

            options {
            directory "/var/cache/bind";
            recursion yes;
            allow-recursion { trusted; };
            listen-on { 192.168.1.24; }; 
            allow-transfer { none; }; 
            
            forwarders {
                    8.8.8.8;
                    8.8.4.4;
    };
            #dnssec-validation auto;

            dnssec-validation no; 

            



            #listen-on-v6 { any; };
```

> /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
//direct resolution area 
zone "fabyfashion.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.fabyfashion.com";

};

//reverse resolution area
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/db.1.168.192";

};
```

> /etc/bind/db.fabyfashion.com

```
;
; BIND Resource Records file for the zone 
fabyfashion.com
;

$TTL    604800
@       IN       SOA    dns.fabyfashion.com. root.fabyfashion.com. (

                              2     ; Serial
                         604800     ; Refresh
                          86400     ; Retry
                        2419200     ; Expire
                         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL

;
;

@                       IN  NS  dns.fabyfashion.com.
dns                     IN  A   192.168.1.24
www                     IN  A   192.168.1.24
LAPTOP-3BEQ0U93         IN  A   192.168.1.64

server                  IN  CNAME   dns.fabyfashion.com.
```

> /etc/bind/db.1.168.192

```
;
; BIND Resource Record File for Reverse Zone 
1.168.192
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN       SOA    dns.fabyfashion.com. root.fabyfashion.com. (
                              2     ; Serial
                        604800      ; Refresh
                         86400      ; Retry
                       2419200      ; Expire
                        604800 )    ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@                       IN  NS  dns.fabyfashion.com.

24                      IN  PTR dns.fabyfashion.com.
24                      IN  PTR www.fabyfashion.com.
64                      IN  PTR LAPTOP-3BEQ0U93.fabyfashion.com.
```

**When checking the syntax, the zones appear correct**

*root@dns:/etc/bind# named-checkconf named.conf.local*

*root@dns:/etc/bind# named-checkzone fabyfashion.com db.fabyfashion.com*

```
zone fabyfashion.com/IN: loaded serial 2
```

OK

*root@dns:/etc/bind# named-checkzone 1.168.192 db.1.168.192*

```
zone 1.168.192/IN: loaded serial 2
```

OK

**testing command |nslookup| dig | host |**

```
nslookup

root@dns:/etc/bind# nslookup 
> fabyfashion.com
Server:     192.168.1.24
Address:    192.168.1.24#53
*** Can't find fabyfashion.com: No answer    

root@dns:/etc/bind# nslookup 
> 192.168.1.24
24.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = www.fabyfashion.com.
24.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = dns.fabyfashion.com.
```

**dig**

```
root@dns:/etc/bind# dig fabyfashion.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-Ubuntu <<>> fabyfashion.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48006
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, 
ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: d56444b5a9f1ffb00100000063b549b2a45a5e97b01355c7 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fabyfashion.com.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
fabyfashion.com.    604800  IN  SOA dns.fabyfashion.com. 
root.fabyfashion.com. 2 604800 86400 2419200 604800

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.24#53(192.168.1.24)
;; WHEN: mié ene 04 03:41:06 CST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117


root@dns:/etc/bind# dig 192.168.1.24

; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-Ubuntu <<>> 192.168.1.24
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 18472
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 28c0b038682a0fa80100000063b54a86d19374e052b3805b (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;192.168.1.24.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           4661    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2023010400 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.24#53(192.168.1.24)
;; WHEN: mié ene 04 03:44:38 CST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 144
```

**host**

```
root@dns:/etc/bind# host 192.168.1.24
24.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer dns.fabyfashion.com.
24.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer www.fabyfashion.com.


root@dns:/etc/bind# host www.fabyfashion.com
www.fabyfashion.com has address 192.168.1.24
```

> root@dns:/etc# systemctl status bind9

```
 ● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-01-04 04:00:06 CST; 2s ago
   Docs: man:named(8)
Process: 14516 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 14518 (named)
  Tasks: 8 (limit: 4492)
 Memory: 26.7M
    CPU: 79ms
 CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
         └─14518 /usr/sbin/named -u bind -4

 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 529
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: zone 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: zone fabyfashion.com/IN: loaded serial 2
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: all zones loaded
 ene 04 04:00:06 dns named[14518]: running

Should I register my domain with a provider?

I HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR SOME ANSWER FOR MONTHS, I WOULD APPRECIATE IF SOMEONE CAN HELP ME IF I'M WRONG ABOUT SOMETHING THANKS
```

Comment: This is English only site. https://translate.google.com/